# How do I create an RSS feed of content from an external website

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, feed

How can I turn the content of a website into an RSS feed?

I would also like the feed to be updated every 3 to 6 hours? Perhaps with a cron job.

This is for an external website, not my own.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at YQL?

[Yahoo YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/)

[image: YQL]

It is a service offered by Yahoo that could be configure to get the content from a remote site for you.

You would then need to run the script on a cron if you wanted to grab the data regularly.

### Example from YQL

This [query](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url=%22http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=yhoo%22%20and%20xpath=%27//div%5B@id=%22yfi_headlines%22%5D/div%5B2%5D/ul/li/a%27) grabs content from CNN based on xpath (Firebug can help you find out the correct xpath query).

Then returns it as XML, meaning it is easy to read into a script.

Comment: I see you edited my question to make it shorter. I don't see how Yahoo YQL is the solution. It seems to be a expressive SQL-like language. How does this turn any website into a RSS feed?

Comment: I see you edited your answer. I am going to see if I can find any tutorials. I was hoping this was possible wit PHP/MYSQL and cron.

Comment: I added a simple example. Which site are you hoping to read the content of?

Comment: Thank you. I am looking are several news sites. Some of them have RSS, but only a summery and not the full post. Others have no feed. I am try to make a mobile news reader app. Which basically is a rss reader with a UI.

Answer (score -1):

Place this where you want to show the rss content in your theme:

```
<?php include_once(ABSPATH.WPINC.'/rss.php');
wp_rss('http://feeds.feedburner.com/wprecipes', 3); ?>
```

Replace "http://feeds.feedburner.com/wprecipes" with your feeed and "3" with the number of articles to display.

Comment: This is a Wordpress specific solution and it actually does not answer the question. This example fetches an RSS feed rather than creates one ;)